# CSRF Protection with Grails Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, grails, spring-security, csrf

I want to implement CSRF protection with Spring Security. My Front end is a JavaScript container that sends request to a Grails backend.

Do I have to set a filter if my front end sends a secure cookie with each request? Is such a filter still integrated in Spring Security?

Edit:

I do not use Forms. I use a REST Api to access my backend.

Answer (score 1):

Your ajax requests should send the CSRF token. See here  for more details: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html